# Different colorplots for scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Hello I want to create a scatter plot to combine both subplots into one, but with the code below only one color is plotted (blue), like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vjfS.jpg. What do I need to change?:
For those who cannot set the picture I've uploaded below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1okFp.jpg
[image]

```
oranges = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.Oranges)
blues = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
RN1 = {}
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        RN1[(i / 100.0, j / 100.0)] = (np.random.uniform(0, 400), np.random.uniform(0, 400))

R_0s = RN1.values()

R_01s = np.array([k[0] / 400.0 for k in R_0s])
R_02s = np.array([k[1] / 400.0 for k in R_0s])
x = [k[0] for k in RN1.keys()]
y = [k[1] for k in RN1.keys()]
oranges.set_array(R_01s)
blues.set_array(R_02s)
s1 = plt.scatter(x, y, c=R_01s, marker='s', cmap=plt.cm.Oranges)
s2 = plt.scatter(x, y, c=R_02s, marker='s', cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.colorbar(oranges)
plt.colorbar(blues)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the two subplots to appear in one figure, like in your second attached image?

Comment: Yes I do. It will be more illustrative  of the phase transition phenomena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be nicely summarized by a single graph. Right now blue scatterplot just completely eclipses the orange one. If you make blue squares semi transparent like this:

```
s2 = plt.scatter(x, y, c=R_02s, marker='s', cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=.3)
```

you can actually see the orange squares behind them, but the overall figure still looks quite messy.

Maybe it would be easier to simply subtract two matrices `R_02s - R_01s` and plot the difference?

Comment: Thanks for taking the interest, see now.

Comment: Actually, with non-random data adding transparency might work slightly better than with random data. Maybe you should play with various ```alpha``` values for both blue and orange plots and see what you will get.

Comment: Yes I tried that. As a matter of fact the first plot was a sum of both, but the thing is that one color presents some percentage of the population with one feature and the other with another feature.

Comment: I actually thought you needed everything on one figure so I was trying to come up with a way to fit everything on it. If you are fine with two different subplots than @DavidG already provided a nice solution.

Comment: @fxhh My bad, I thought you wanted 2 figures. I've deleted my answer

Comment: Huh, if you really only want one figure I think there are two options: (1) plotting it as a difference using a diverging colormap like ```RdBu``` (so that 0 corresponds to ```R_01s == R_02s```) or (2) playing with ```alpha``` and background color.